# Using Python to Access Web Data with Regular Expression is not working

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

I am doing Python for everybody's Course on Coursera so I just learned how to access the file from the Web with Python.

So here what I am trying to do is to extract the Email from the lines which are starting with the From: but I am getting nothing.

There are emails in lines which are starting with `From:` because I have done this with File Handling method but it's not working when I tried it on file which is on Server so I guess it is to do with the white space.

So Anyways Guys, Help me I am stuck

```
import socket
import re
dic = dict()
mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
except:
    print("Can't find the server.\nCheck your internet Connection")
cmd = 'GET http://data.pr4e.org/mbox-short.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n'.encode()
try:
    mysock.send(cmd)
except:
    print("Connection Lost:\nCheck your Internet Connection")
while True:
    data = mysock.recv(512)
    if len(data)  < 1:
        break
    data = data.decode()
    data = data.rstrip()
    k = re.findall('^From:.(\S+@\S+)', data)
    if (len(k)) > 0:
        print(k)
```

[This is the Link from where you can download the file](http://data.pr4e.org/mbox-short.txt)

Comment: You recognize it's some whitespace problem but you haven't even included the text/file you're trying to match against. Have you tried a regex debugging tool? e.g. https://www.debuggex.com/ or want to include the text you're trying to match against?

Comment: Brother, I have just added the link from where you can download the file.
http://data.pr4e.org/mbox-short.txt

Comment: Your regex expects a start of `From:` but there's no `:` in the file, it's just `From `

Comment: No there are lines which are starting with From:
27 lines are there which are starting with From: to be Precise
`count = 0
fhand = open("test.txt") #change the file name as you have saved
for line in fhand:
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        count = count + 1
print(count)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get the emails using

```
k = re.findall(r'(?m)^From:\s*(\S+@\S+)', data)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YaxEeA/1).

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `From:`  - a literal string
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+@\S+)` - Capturing group 1 (the output of `re.findall` will only contain this value): one or more non-whitespace chars, `@` and one or more non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I found the better way of what I am doing here.
I can do this easily and more efficiently by using the urllib.request library.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import re

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://data.pr4e.org/mbox-short.txt')
for line in fhand:
    k = re.findall(r'(?m)^From:\s*(\S+@\S+)', line)
    if len(k) > 1:
       print(k)
```